# File names being saved as NULL to database

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I am using following code to upload, rename and save multiple file names to the database table.

**PHP:**

```
   require('../includes/config.php');
$apdtitle = htmlspecialchars(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apdtitle')));
$apdcategory = 'Education';
$apdsubcategory = 'Books';
$pnumber = htmlspecialchars(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pnumber')));
$prodprice = htmlspecialchars(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prodprice')));
$apddescription = htmlspecialchars(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apddescription')));
$location = htmlspecialchars(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pstloct')));
$view = '1';
$added_on = date('d-M-y');
$status = 'active';
$username ='sanoj';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir = "../upload/";
            $d = compress($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 60);
            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                if
                (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt )) {
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
                } else {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
            if (!empty($row[1])) {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
                eval($codestr);
            } else {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
                eval($codestr);
            }
        }
    }
    $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";
    $thumb_directory = "../upload/thumb/";
    $dir_handle = opendir($orig_directory);
    if ($dir_handle > 1) {
        $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_type = array();
        $ext = '';
        $title = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file_type = \explode('.', $file_name);
            $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
            $title1 = implode('.', $file_type);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title1);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
                $nw = 250;
                $nh = 180;
                $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
                $stype1 = explode(".", $source);
                $stype = $stype1[count($stype1) - 1];
                $dest = "../upload/thumb/{$file_name}";
                $size = getimagesize($source);
                $w = $size[0];
                $h = $size[1];
                switch ($stype) {
                    case 'gif':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                        break;
                    case 'jpg':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                        break;
                }
                $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                imagepng($dimg, $dest);
            }
        }closedir($dir_handle);
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(apdtitle, apdcategory, apdsubcategory, posted, usernme, view, location, pnumber, prodprice, apddescription, img1, img2, img3, img4, status)"
            . " VALUES (:apdtitle, :apdcategory, :apdsubcategory, :posted, :usernme, :view, :location, :pnumber, :prodprice, :apddescription, :img1, :img2, :img3, :img4, :status)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdtitle', $apdtitle, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdcategory', $apdcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdsubcategory', $apdsubcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':posted', $added_on, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usernme', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':view', $view, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pnumber', $pnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prodprice', $prodprice, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apddescription', $apddescription, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img1', $file1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img2', $file2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img3', $file3);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img4', $file4);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../../index.php');
    }exit;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
```

All the other inputs are being saved to database table properly but uploaded image names are not being saved. They are being saved as NULL values.

Can someone please sort out what's wrong in the code?

**Compress**

```
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `eval($codestr)`?

Comment: getting file name of uploaded image

Comment: @sanojlawrence - you are sending 3 arguments in `move_uploaded_file()`. Is that the reason for file not being uploaded? Also, are you getting "Couldn't upload file "  echo in the page itself?

Comment: @RaviManiyar Yes, what is the solution

Comment: What does `$d = compress($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 50);` this line do? And why are you sending $d to `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: `2097152000` is not 2MB? its 2GB

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` has only 2 parameters! What is $d??

Comment: Instead of `eval()` you could do: `${'file'.(++$key)} = $row[0];`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Yes 2097152000,  its 2 GB.

Comment: Instead of using non recommended `eval()`, why can't you create an array of the $file variable and use it in the loop? Also 3 parameters in `move_uploaded_file()` is incorrect.

Comment: @RaviManiyar `$d` its image compression

Comment: But you can't pass it in `move_uploaded_file()`. It accepts only 2 parameters.

Comment: @RaviManiyar so that is the reason am getting error, so how do i compress image while uploading. any ideas

Comment: @RaviManiyar after changing `(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt ))` file name are saved to database. but how do i compress images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution, /below code can upload and save file name to Database, and can compress uploaded images.

**COde**

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $uploadedFiles = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
            $errors = array();
            $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if ($file_type == "image/gif") {
                $sExt = ".gif";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg") {
                $sExt = ".jpg";
            } elseif ($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png") {
                $sExt = ".png";
            }
            if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif', '.jpg', '.png'))) {
                $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir = "../upload/";

            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);
                }
                if
                (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
                } else {
                    echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], 0);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
            if (!empty($row[1])) {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = $row[0];';
                eval($codestr);
            } else {
                $codestr = '$file' . ($key + 1) . ' = NULL;';
                eval($codestr);
            }
        }
    }
    $orig_directory = "$desired_dir";
    $thumb_directory = "../upload/thumb/";
    $dir_handle = opendir($orig_directory);
    if ($dir_handle > 1) {
        $allowed_types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_type = array();
        $ext = '';
        $title = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            if ($file_name == '.' || $file_name == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file_type = \explode('.', $file_name);
            $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
            $title1 = implode('.', $file_type);
            $title = htmlspecialchars($title1);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types)) {
                $nw = 250;
                $nh = 180;
                $source = "$desired_dir{$file_name}";
                $stype1 = explode(".", $source);
                $stype = $stype1[count($stype1) - 1];
                $dest = "../upload/thumb/{$file_name}";
                $size = getimagesize($source);
                $w = $size[0];
                $h = $size[1];
                switch ($stype) {
                    case 'gif':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                        break;
                    case 'jpg':
                        $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                        break;
                }
                $dimg = resizePreservingAspectRatio($simg, $nw, $nh);
                imagepng($dimg, $dest);
                compress($source, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name, 50);
            }
        }closedir($dir_handle);
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO allpostdata(apdtitle, apdcategory, apdsubcategory, brand, model, posted, usernme, view, location, pnumber, prodprice, apddescription, img1, img2, img3, img4, status)"
            . " VALUES (:apdtitle, :apdcategory, :apdsubcategory, :brand, :model, :posted, :usernme, :view, :location, :pnumber, :prodprice, :apddescription, :img1, :img2, :img3, :img4, :status)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdtitle', $apdtitle, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdcategory', $apdcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apdsubcategory', $apdsubcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':brand', $pstbrnd, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':model', $pstmdl, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':posted', $added_on, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usernme', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':view', $view, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pnumber', $pnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prodprice', $prodprice, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apddescription', $apddescription, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR, 6);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img1', $file1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img2', $file2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img3', $file3);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img4', $file4);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }exit;
}

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}

function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight) {
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight)) {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    } else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio) {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    } else {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    return $targetImg;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per discussions in the comments, you would definitely need to remove third parameter from `move_uploaded_file()` which will fulfil your first need to save the image names into the database.

Regarding optimizing images, you can use [this](https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer) GIT Hub library. Which uses command line tools like [JpegOptim](http://freecode.com/projects/jpegoptim) and [PngQuant](https://pngquant.org/) which can help you generate lossless optimizations of the images. Which will reduce the size of image by Not losing the quality. Your both the purposes will be resolved.

Comment: i have added compress function to question, is there a way to add to my code

Comment: Your compression code looks fine. You are already compressing the images and saving the file name to the database. you can also save the relative path along with file name in the database: `if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, $d)) {
                    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array("$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 1);`

Comment: as per your answer i removed the third parameter in `move_uploaded_file()` then how do i compress image

Comment: First you move the file and then compress it.

Comment: Upload the file, move the file, compress the file and save the path into database.

Comment: it doesn't help me as per your answer i removed the third parameter in `move_uploaded_file()` then how do i compress image

Comment: @sanojlawrence - `move_uploaded_file()` does not have 3 parameters. So definitely you have to remove the third one. The uploaded file name should be saved in database using following code: `if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, $d)) { $uploadedFiles[$key] = array("$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 1);` .. And you can then compress the image as per your function. Compression has nothing to do with File name being saved in database.

Comment: Dear @sanojlawrence - its ok if you don't vote it up, but this is your own line of code `compress($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt, 60);` which does the compression. I have already provided link for better compression plugins. Many thanks. Hope you will now manage your way.